# why does openMP needs so long?

Tags: c++, openmp

I just spent quite some time trying to get this loop openMPed, but for 2 threads, it doubles Wall time! Am I missing something important?

The overall task is to read in a big file (~ 1GB) in parallel, an ifstream is divided into several stringbuffer and these are used to insert the data into the structs Symbol. Up to here everything is fast. Also giving the loop private variables str and locVec to operate on doesn't change something.

```
vector<string> strbuf; // filled from ifstream
vector< vector <Symbol> > symVec; // to be filled


#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) default(none) shared(strbuf, symVec)
for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    string str = strbuf[i];
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    // no problem until here

    // this is where it slows down:
    vector<Symbol> locVec;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Symbol>(ss), std::istream_iterator<Symbol>(), std::back_inserter(locVec));


    symVec[i] = locVec;
}
```

EDIT::
Sorry for being unprecise, but the file content is already read in sequencially and divided into the strbufs at this point. The file is closed. Within the loop there is no file access.

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to do sequential I/O on a file rather than I/O at different sections of a file. This essentially boils down to causing a lot of seeks on the underlying device (I'm assuming a disk here). This also increases the amount of underlying system calls required to read the file into said buffers. You're better off using 1 thread to read the file in it's totality sequentially (maybe `mmap()` with `MAP_POPULATE`) and assigning processing to different threads.

Another option is to use calls such as `aio_read()` to handle reading in different sections if for some reason you really do not want to read the file all at once.

Without all the code I cannot be completely sure but remember that simply opening a file does not guarantee it's content to be in memory and reading from a file will cause page faults that will then cause the actual file contents to be read so even if you're not explicitly trying to read from the file using a read/write the OS will take care of that for you.

Comment: Sorry for being unprecise, but the file content is already read in sequencially and divided into the strbufs at this point. The file is closed. Within the loop there is no file access.

Comment: @niko Why even bother breaking into streambufs? Just find the end of the file and read it into one large buffer at that point. It's probably faster. The copy operations are probably what's hurting you.